# Mysql select * from tables where primary_key in (1,2,,...) very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am having trouble with one of my queries which is very slow from time to time.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE primary_key IN (1,2,...)
```

very slow sometimes even 5s for some 100 entries. Obviously we have index on the primary key. Is there any way to optimize this query. The table is slightly big about 100 million entries.

Comment: Do you need to select *? Can't you just specify the columns you want?

Comment: we will be needed most of the columns in the table. so it does not make sense for us to specify columns atleast in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an EXPLAIN, perhaps there's something fishy going on.

Also, if this is a MyISAM database table and you have high concurrent INSERTs, the table will be locked during the inserts so your SELECTs may block during this time.

Comment: 1) We use Innodb not MyISAM

2) EXPLAIN  for an example with 10 entries

+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | <table> | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   10 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+

Comment: Thanks - as expected. How many rows are you selecting at a time with the IN clause? If its "a lot", it may just take a bit of time regardless, due to the random seeking of fetching these rows. Try posting an EXPLAIN plan for a production query that is slow on your big table. Also, you may want to consider contacting a MySQL perf expert (see mysqlperformanceblog.com ?) and see if they can assist?

Answer (score 0):

For a 100M records table you can't really do much in terms of query optimization as it is simple enough. What you could look into is MySQL config tuning.

In case your table is InnoDB/XtraDB (and if it's not i'd recommend to use those engines) you might want to look into `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable - it's essential that used index fits into memory to achieve best performance for your queries.

Comment: Is there any formula/way to calculate optimal value of innodb_buffer_pool_size? We have 2.5G now. It is more of a gut call than a calculated number.

Comment: if your mysql server is running nothing but mysql then just set that variable to 80% of total ram. in short - give it as much as you can, it won't hurt.